# Add numbers corresponding to different hours associated with two different dates in R

Tags: r, dataframe, addition

I have the following dataframe

```
set.seed(1000) 
data <- data.frame(date = sort(rep(Sys.Date()-1:3, 5)), 
                   hour = rep(0:4, 3), 
                 values = round(rexp(15),2))

      date     hour  values
1  2016-04-25    0   1.00
2  2016-04-25    1   0.52
3  2016-04-25    2   2.44
4  2016-04-25    3   2.16
5  2016-04-25    4   0.48
6  2016-04-26    0   0.17
7  2016-04-26    1   1.56
8  2016-04-26    2   0.51
9  2016-04-26    3   0.96
10 2016-04-26    4   0.05
11 2016-04-27    0   0.75
12 2016-04-27    1   1.69
13 2016-04-27    2   0.61
14 2016-04-27    3   0.85
15 2016-04-27    4   2.23
```

I want to add numbers correspondig to the column values, these numbers should be associated with the hours from

2 to 1 closed. However, the number 2 correspond to one date, and the number 1 is associated with the next date.

I want a final dataframe like

```
  date    sumvalue
2016-04-26 6.81
2016-04-27 3.96
```

Someone knows an elegant way to do this? I want to do the same with a huge dataframe.

Kind regards

Comment: 2 and 1 are regarded

Comment: I think it means from hour 2 on day 1 (2016-04-25) to hour 1 on day 2 (2016-04-26) so `2.44 + 2.16 + 0.48 + 0.17 + 1.56` = `6.81` and so on

Comment: It is right the explanation of Colin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to get the expected output

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, {Un1 <- unique(date)
             i1 <- which(hour==2 & date %in% Un1[-length(Un1)])
             i2 <- which(hour==1 & date %in% Un1[-1])
             v1 <- unlist(Map(function(x,y) sum(values[seq(x,y)]),
                i1, i2))
      list(date = Un1[-1], sumvalue= v1)}]
#         date sumvalue 
#1: 2016-04-26     6.81
#2: 2016-04-27     3.96
```

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted to do, thanks a lot akrun

Comment: Thanks a lot again akrun, it is my first time participating in this way through this site.